# AX 2009 Code Propagation with Load Balancing

Tags: load-balancing, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I'm curious how AX 2009 handles code propagation when operating in a load balanced environment.

We have recently converted our AX server infrastructure from a single AOS instance to 3 AOS instances, one of which is a dedicated load balancer (effectively 2 user-facing servers). All share the same application files and database. Since then, we have had one user who has been having trouble receiving code updates made to the system. The changes generally take a few days before they can see it, and the changes don't seem to update all at once.

For example, a value was added to an ENUM field, and they were not able to see it on a form where it was used (though others connected to the same instance were). Now, this user can see the field in the dropdown as expected, but when connected to one of the instances it will not flow onto a report as it should. When connected to the other instance it works fine, and for any other user connected to either instance it works properly.

I'm not certain if this is related to the infrastructure changes, but it does seem odd that only one user is experiencing it. My understanding was that with this setup, code changes would propagate across the servers either immediately (due to sharing the Application Files), or at least in a reasonable amount of time (<1 day). Is this correct or have I been misinformed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your cache problems seems to be per user, then go learn about [AUC files](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php/Object_caching).

The files are store on the client computer and can be tricky to keep in sync. There are [other problems](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadaxsupport/archive/2010/01/25/identical-ax-2009-auc-file-created-for-multiple-ax-installations.aspx) as well.

Start AX by a script, [delete the AUC file before starting AX](http://dynamics-ax.blogspot.dk/2005/11/axapta-client-cache.html).

There is no cache coherency between AOS instances: import an XPO on one AOS server, and it is not visible on the other. You will either have to flush the cache manually or restart the other AOS. The simplest thing is to import on each server, this is especially true for labels, as this is the only way to bring labels in sync to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I am sort of curious to this as well, but what I do know, is that if a user has access to the AOT (member of admin or a group with developer access), the client will cache AOT-elements more aggressively than if not having developer access.

Elements (like an Enum) might be cached at client level, but also at AOS-level. Restarting the AOS (service) would flush out memory for that service, forcing it to reload elements upon restart.

I guess what I am suggesting is that you make sure the element is not cached client side. Either restart the client, or run the "Refresh AOD" from the developer tools menu. If that doesn't help, try restaring the AOS the client connects to, and see if that helps.

I think it is safe to say, if you want to be absolutely sure every user has the most recent "copy" of any element, you should not develop on the application files shared by all of these services, but rather develop in an environment with 1 AOS. And when you need to move things to production, you need to take down all AOSes in production and move the chances over while the system is down.

Comment: Restarting the client didn't seem to help the issue. However we did trigger a restart of the AOS last night, which seems to have fixed the problem (I'm guessing because it cleared the server cache). 

Because we perform small updates during business hours, taking the system completely offline during an update isn't a reasonable solution at this time. Outside of restarting the AOS process, is there any known way of forcing the code to sync?

Answer (score 0):

In such cases it is often difficult to find the exact cause for a specific case.
I try to follow some best practices to avoid such situations:
 - Use separate environment for developing 
 - Deploy code changes using layer files, not XPOs
 - When deploying, stop all AOSs, deploy files, delete index files in the application directory, start one AOSs, compile, sync DB, start other AOS (or even shut down all and start again)
 - Try to have latest kernel versions for AOSs and client